# How do I make a registry entry with command prompt?

Tags: batch

How can I make command prompt (batch) add this entry to the registry?

To set the value of the LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy registry entry

> Open the registry key:
>
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System
>
> If the entry LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy does not yet exist,
>   right-click System, and then click Edit, New, and DWord (32-bit)
>   value. Type the name LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy, and then set its
>   value to 1.

It says i need to navigate to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System and create a new DWord (32-bit) named LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy with the value of 1

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

```
@echo off
reg add HKLM\SOFTWARE\MICROSOFT\WINDOWS\CURRENTVERSION\POLICIES\SYSTEM /V LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy /t REG_DWORD /d 1
if %errorlevel%==0 echo Key added successfully
pause
exit
```

--RUN THE SCRIPT AS ADMINISTRATOR.

Answer (score 0):

Use the REG command - REG /? for help.  You can use a test system first to export the key you need then use REG to import it or just use REG to create it.

Note: to write to HKLM (or any key other than HKCU) you'll need admin rights.

Since examples and links must be given (apparently):
http://ss64.com/nt/reg.html

```
   REG QUERY [ROOT\]RegKey /v ValueName [/s]
```

REG QUERY [ROOT]RegKey /ve  --This returns the (default) value

REG ADD [ROOT]RegKey /v ValueName [/t DataType] [/S Separator] [/d Data] [/f]
   REG ADD [ROOT]RegKey /ve [/d Data] [/f]  -- Set the (default) value

REG DELETE [ROOT]RegKey /v ValueName [/f]
   REG DELETE [ROOT]RegKey /ve [/f]  -- Remove the (default) value
   REG DELETE [ROOT]RegKey /va [/f]  -- Delete all values under this key

REG COPY  [\SourceMachine][ROOT]RegKey [\DestMachine][ROOT]RegKey

REG EXPORT [ROOT]RegKey FileName.reg
   REG IMPORT FileName.reg
   REG SAVE [ROOT]RegKey FileName.hiv
   REG RESTORE \MachineName[ROOT]\KeyName FileName.hiv

REG LOAD KeyName FileName
   REG UNLOAD KeyName

REG COMPARE [ROOT]RegKey [ROOT]RegKey [/v ValueName] [Output] [/s]
   REG COMPARE [ROOT]RegKey [ROOT]RegKey [/ve] [Output] [/s]

Answer (score 0):

This MSDN topic tells how to construct a `.reg` file which you can apply from the command-line:

*[How to add, modify, or delete registry subkeys and values by using a .reg file](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/310516)*

Given a `.reg` file, "running" it will trigger the file-associations and load it as noted near the end of the article:

```
regedit.exe /s path of .reg file
```

Also, as noted in *[Is it possible to modify a registry entry via a .bat/.cmd script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130193/is-it-possible-to-modify-a-registry-entry-via-a-bat-cmd-script)*, there are tools such as `REG` which are useful.  This is documented also on MSDN:

*[Reg](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732643.aspx) Performs operations on registry subkey information and values in registry entries*

Answer (score 0):

Here's the resource you're looking for. You can do

http://www.computerhope.com/reg.htm

```
# List subkeys
REG QUERY HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System
# Add a key of type with data
REG ADD HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System\ /v LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy /t REG_DWORD /d 1
```

Additional resources:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/cc742162.aspx #Reg Add

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/264584

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/310516